How can I convert this VB6 code to C# while maintaining the original logic?
I'm working on modernizing a VB6 application by converting it to C#. One challenge I’ve encountered is translating certain VB6 patterns to their C# equivalents, especially when dealing with APIs and data structures.
Dim myArray(1 To 5) As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    myArray(i) = i * 10
Next i

Debug.Print myArray(3)


I tried converting it like this:
int[] myArray = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = i * 10;
}

Console.WriteLine(myArray[2]); // Equivalent to VB6's myArray(3)?


It works, but there are a few things I'm unsure about:
In VB6, arrays start at 1 (or a custom lower bound). In C#, arrays are zero-based. How do I properly account for this when migrating more complex VB6 logic?
How should I handle VB6's LBound and UBound when they appear in larger projects? Is there a C# equivalent or a better migration pattern?

Overall what's being asked here sounds too broad to be effectively answered.  Though as a general word of advice, when migrating an application to an entirely different language/framework/technology/etc. I'd recommend not attempting to perform a line-by-line equivalent and instead implement the application feature-by-feature.  Approaches which made sense in one technology may make no sense at all in another, and trying to keep those approaches intact tends to produce very poor results.

Your conversion above looks fine to me. Whether or not your VB arrays have custom lower bound, your code needs to be updated to assume a base of zero. There are no shortcuts that I am aware of.

In VB6 arrays start at 0 (zero) not 1 unless you set the lower bound! Try Dim MyArray(5) and then Debug.Print Lbound(MyArray), uBound)MyArrray). The result is 0 5.

To replicate a 1-based array, I adjusted the loop to shift the logic while keeping the C# array itself zero-based. This ensures I don’t lose compatibility with idiomatic C# practices. Also in C#, LBound isn't needed since arrays always start at 0. For UBound, I use the Length and subtract one to get the last index.
  // Since VB6 arrays often start at 1, I account for that by adjusting the loop
    int[] myArray = new int[5];
    
    // Populate the array
    for (int i = 1; i <= myArray.Length; i++) // Mimics 1-based logic
    {
        myArray[i - 1] = i * 10; // Offset by -1 to account for zero-based indexing
    }
    
    // Access the "3rd" element in 1-based terms (index 2 in 0-based terms)
    Console.WriteLine(myArray[2]);

This worked well when directly porting code but allowed the C# array to remain zero-based.
In VB6, Debug.Print outputs to the Immediate Window. I used Console.WriteLine. For GUI-based apps, something like MessageBox.Show might be closer.

If you really want your indexes to go from 1 to 5, then simply make your array one element too big, and then ignore the slot at index 0 (zero):
int[] myArray = new int[6]; // one element bigger than necessary
for (int i = 1; i < myArray.Length; i++) // starts at 1 (one)
{
    myArray[i] = i * 10;
}
Console.WriteLine(myArray[3]); // actually using 3 for the third element

Of course, this only works for a lower bound of 1 (one).
